# Selfhost Web API parameter passing

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection

I have middle ware with different components interacting with each other. I'm building now a selfhost Web API using OWIN and .NET WebAPI to interact with 3rd parties. My problem is that I need to pass an object reference to my controller so when the controller is called via a GET or POST request it can call function of the passed object. Dependency injection is not helping me in this case cause I need to pass a reference of an existing object and not create a new one.

The WebAPI is created in the ExternalWebAPI class start function:

```
public virtual void Start()
{
   server = WebApp.Start<WebAPIStartup>(url: baseAddress);
   UpdateStatus("Active","True");
}
```

Right now my controller looks like this:

```
class TradesController:ApiController
{       
    TradeRequest PostTradeRequest(TradeRequest tradeRequest)
    {

        return tradeRequest;
    }
}
```

What I want to be able to do is to pass a reference to the `TradesController` of the `ExternalWebAPI` class using `this`so from `TradesController` I would be bale to call `ExternalWebAPI` functions. I looked into DI, but I haven't found a good way to do it since it important to pass the instance of the `ExternalWebAPI` class that has started up the WebAPI cause it has other methods and events that has to be called once the `TradesController`'s  `PostTradeRequest` is called.

Comment: It's usually quite possible to pass existing objects with DI, most DI frameworks support some form of object lifetime management options. What DI are you using?

Comment: I have looked into Unity and Ninject, but all I found from code samples is to assign a class to interface and use constructor injection but the samples were creating a new object instance and not using the reference so it was not something I have been looking for.

Comment: For unity you can take a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660872%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx. For Ninject they are called object scopes see here: https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes

Comment: With the unity container, there is a [RegisterInstance method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.iunitycontainer.registerinstance.aspx). This method allows you to inject an existing instance. However, I think that if you give us an idea about the bigger picture, we would be able to help you better.

Comment: Worked with RegisterInstance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going down the wrong path here. Your API should take data in and send data out. It should not hold references to anything or call functions on those references. Call you API for the data you need to update your local reference and then call the function on that object as needed.

Comment: Because it's a middle ware communicating with 3rd party using the WebAPI I need the WebAPI to get data using POST, but then I need to be able to pass that data down the chain to other components in the middleware before I can send a response.